# Sort Numeric String in sql query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sorting, select

I have this data in a column in my datatable:

```
j1
ds2
b15
```

I need to select and sort this column. Using below code :

```
var drs = inpDataTable.Select($"myCol<> 'jj'", "myCol Desc");
```

returns wrong answer!:

```
j1
b15
ds2
```

How can I get true answer?
Chars aren't important.
I'm using SQL Server

Comment: The rules for DataTable.Select are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0). But you are much better off using LINQ if you can `inpDataTable.Cast<DataRow>().Where(=> ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by just numeric in the `mycol` then you need `PATINDEX` as follows:

```
order by cast(SUBSTRING(mycol, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', mycol), LEN(mycol)) as INT)
```

Comment: Thanks, Does this work in DataTable.Select() in C# ?

Comment: I am expert of database. I have no idea about C#